# Edit a list while comparing it to another list as constraints

Tags: python, list, compare

I've got a list with some literals, and another list with only the needed literals inside, I want to get an output with the relevant literals and their sign, how should I compute this output? thanks a lot

```
list=[0,-1, 2, 3, 11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33, 50, 20, 30]

needed literals = [11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]

output = [11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33]
```

EDIT: every one of the literals is also a string, e.g: '11', '-12', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough with a list comprehension:

```
literal_list = [0, -1, 2, 3, 11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33, 50, 20, 30]
needed_literals = [11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
output = [n for n in literal_list if abs(n) in needed_literals]
#=> [11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33]
```

If the elements of both lists are strings instead of integers, you can do the conversion in the condition:

```
output = [n for n in literal_list if str(abs(int(n))) in needed_literals]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lis=[0,-1, 2, 3, 11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33, 50, 20, 30]

literals = [11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]

output=[]
li=0
i=0
for i in range(0,len(lis)-1):
   if mod(literals[li])==lis[i]:
      output.append(lis[i])
      li+=1
   i+=1
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list=[0,-1, 2, 3, 11, 12, -13, 21, -22, 23, 31, -32, 33, 50, 20, 30]
needed_literals = [11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
```

With duplicates:

```
output = [ for i in input_list if abs(i) in needed_literals]
```

Without duplicates:

```
output = [ for i in set(input_list) if abs(i) in needed_literals]
```